# Reactjs and public/dist/images folder

Tags: css, reactjs

I am working on an application - and there is a request to add a custom icon to the td element.

I want to use some css method to do this -

```
background-image: url("...image url")
```

I've placed the image inside the public/dist/assets folder - but I am unable to render the image.

Comment: Is your app created with `create-react-app`?

Comment: don't think so - its a monolithic old app